# Using apply function in R to a particular function value

Tags: r, matrix, apply, lapply, sapply

So I have a function with multiple return values. An example of this would be the following:

```
Test.function <- function(x){
a <- x^2
b <- x^3
c <- x^4
return(list(
"a" =  a,
"b" =  b,
"c"  = c
))
}
```

Now, I would like to use the 'apply' function to extract only one of these values. eg 'b'. The following code produces a list of 10 objects all each with a vector of a's, b's and c's. I'd like to create a matrix of just the b's.

```
apply(matrix(rnorm(200),nrow = 20), 2, FUN= Test.function)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lapply` or `sapply` you can subset the elements from the list named "b"

```
set.seed(100)
fulloutput <- apply(matrix(rnorm(200),nrow = 20), 2, FUN= Test.function)
lapply(fulloutput, "[[", "b")
```

Or in one line:

```
sapply(apply(matrix(rnorm(200),nrow = 20), 2, FUN= Test.function), "[[", "b")
```